# Javascript Image.onload triggering too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This might look like a duplicate question, but I assure you it's not.

I'm loading several dynamic images from an AJAX call that's provided by a server side servlet. I need to chop up the image into three parts, but I cannot do that until the image is loaded. This brings me to my issue. I have an onload trigger for each image, but it triggers before the image attributes are available (such as height, width, etc). So my code is failing over to error handling.

```
var imageData = [];

$( document ).ready(function() {
    preLoadImages();
});

function preLoadImages() {
    <c:forEach var="table" items="${tables}">
    var tmpImage = new imageObject(<c:out value="${table.tableRowId}" />);
    imageData.push(tmpImage);
    </c:forEach>

    for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {
        ajaxGetmainImages(i);
    }
}

function imageObject(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.mainImage = new Image();
    this.topImage = new Image();
    this.middleImage = new Image();
    this.bottomImage = new Image();
}

function split_3(i) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    if (imageData[i].mainImage.height > 2500) {
        $("#error_container-" + imageData[i].id).attr('display', "none");
        //document.getElementById('error_container').style.display = "none";

        var newWidth = imageData[i].mainImage.width;
        var newHeight = imageData[i].mainImage.height / 3;
        canvas.width = newWidth;
        canvas.height = newHeight;

        ctx.drawImage(imageData[i].mainImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        imageData[i].topImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();

        ctx.drawImage(imageData[i].mainImage, 0, (newHeight), newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        imageData[i].middleImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();

        ctx.drawImage(imageData[i].mainImage, 0, ((newHeight * 2)), newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        imageData[i].bottomImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();

        $("#left_image-" + imageData[i].id).attr('src', imageData[i].topImage.src);
        $("#right_image-" + imageData[i].id).attr('src', imageData[i].bottomImage.src);
    }
    else {
        $("#slider_container-" + imageData[i].id).attr('display', "none");
        $("#error_image-" + imageData[i].id).attr('src', imageData[i].mainImage.src);
    }

}

function ajaxGetmainImages(i)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: baseURL + '/admin/' + imageData[i].id,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success:function(data){
            imageData[i].mainImage.onload = split_3(i);
            imageData[i].mainImage.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data.image;
            //imageData[i].mainImage.addEventListener("load", split_3(i));
        },
        error:function(result){
            //$("#" + id + 'status').html("<img src='../resources/img/status-unknown-16.png' alt='Unknown'>");
        }
    });
}
```

The image ID's are provided via a model from the servlet that provides the page. With that I build unique URLs to poll for each image. This code works. I have it functioning in a separate page where I only deal with a single image (the image is divided so that a slider can be used to compare images). However, when I try to use multiple images the height of the image is always 0 during the onload function. If I set breakpoints in the split_3 function I can see that when the *next* image is being processed, the previous one now has a non-zero height value (the correct value).

I have tried Chrome Stable, Chrome Beta, Chrome Dev, Firefox, and Opera and the results are all the same. onload seems to trigger a tad too early, and I have no idea why.

Edit: some additional info. The images are ultimately loading. If the server side code is not able to acquire the proper image it serves up a default placeholder (hence the else > "error_image"). But the placeholder does not need to be split. So what I'm getting on my page is the entire 3x height image in the error placeholder. That's the ultimate issue.

Comment: `imageObject` doesn't seem to have `tableImage` property. You are doing `imageData[i].tableImage.onload = split_3(i);`. Even if `imageObject` had `tableImage` property, where are you setting it's src?

Comment: @VivekAthalye thanks for taking the time. I messed up when copying the code over. Your observation is correct, but my code doesn't have that issue. I've fixed my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded. I discovered the issue. The problem was that I was calling the onload method as such:

```
tableData[i].tableImage.onload = split_3(i);
```

Which calls it immediately because it's not a *reference*. I fixed the code with the following.

```
tableData[i].tableImage.indexId = i;
tableData[i].tableImage.onload = split_3;
tableData[i].tableImage.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data.image;
```

I also stored the current index inside the image object itself. That way I can call it back when the onload is triggered.

```
function split_3() {
    var i = this.indexId;
```

And the rest of the code works without any changes.

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `addEventListener` must be a reference to a function. You're calling the function immediately and passing the result to `addEventListener`. It should be:

```
imageData[i].mainImage.addEventListener("load", function() {
    split_3(i));
});
```

or with `onload`:

```
imageData[i].onload = function() { split_3(i); };
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the pasted code. What I originally pasted was just something I was testing (unsuccessfully).